# Inkwell does not appear in custom button

Tags: flutter

When the `sized box` tapped, the `ripple effect` should happen on top of the widget. But it does not appear. The sized box appears, but ripple effect is not.

```
      Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: widget.width,
            height: widget.height,
            child: Material(color: Colors.yellow, child: widget.icon
               
                ),

          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: widget.width,
            height: widget.height,
            child: InkWell(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                splashColor: Colors.purple,
                onTap: () {}),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]);
```

**EDIT:** `Wrapped` the whole `stack` with the `inkwell` but still ripple does not appear.

```
InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        splashColor: Colors.purple,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: widget.width,
              height: widget.height,
              child: Material(color: Colors.yellow, child: widget.icon
                  
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `InkWell` above icon that will give a `ripple effect`

```
   Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 48,
              width: 48,
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: InkWell(
                  splashColor: Colors.purple,
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

**OR**

```
   Material(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.purple,
                onTap: () {},
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must put the sized box as child of inkwell (or even move the complete stack into the inkwell child).

Inkwell is applied to its children.

Comment: Wrapped the whole stack with the inkwell but still ripple does not appear. I added code above as the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 InkWell(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              splashColor: Colors.purple,
              onTap: () {
                print('HEY');
              },
              child: SizedBox(
                width: widget.width,
                height: widget.height,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: this does not contain the `child: Material(color: Colors.yellow, child: widget.icon`  once I put it as a child to your code, the ripple no longer appears

Answer (score 0):

add `onTap(){}` to the inkWell, even if its not used. I think this fixes it, haven't tried it out tho. Also try wrapping the InkWell with a Material widget.